# Find a continuous function that has directional derivatives and partial derivatives but not differentiable

Tags: analysis

Find a continuous function $f(\mathbf{x})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

(1)$f(\mathbf{x})$ has all directional derivatives and partial derivatives at $\mathbf{x}=0$;

(2)$f(\mathbf{x})$ is not differentiable at $\mathbf{x}=0$.

For $n=2$, I've found an example:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} & x^2+y^2\neq 0\\
0 & otherwise \end{cases}$$
Unfortunately, for $n\ge 3$,
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{x_1^2x_2^2\cdots x_n^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{3/2}} & x_1^2+_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2\neq 0\\
0 & otherwise \end{cases}$$
no longer works.

Comment: @ziyu_Of Try to see what is the importance of the $\frac 32$ exponent in the $n=2$ case. Maybe  this way you can guess what the exponent should be for general $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{cases}\frac{x_1^{\,2}x_2^{\,2}}{(x_1^{\,2}+x_2^{\,2})^{3/2}}&\text{ if }x_1^{\,2}+x_2^{\,2}\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$